# Unable to run chorme headless on Amazon Linux / centos 7 for (puppeteer)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos

I have install all required depnendencies after that running this command

$ ./chrome --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/
It shows me this error which I am not able to resolve it.

./chrome: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0)
./chrome: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libatspi.so.0)

./chrome: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset

uname -a: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Does your installed distribution have a desktop environment?

Comment: No, I use ssh to connect, I am trying to generate pdf using nodejs puppeteer. which is headless chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the chrome that comes with more recent versions of puppeteer to work. I only got it to work by installing 2.0.0 instead with

```
npm install puppeteer@2.0.0
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904111/installing-puppeteer-2-elastickbeanstalk/61370778#61370778

More info at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5379